# Ho to pass local apache jmeter path in yaml

Tags: taurus

`enter code here`I am setting jmeter path in yaml in below way,while running the script through yaml getting error as No field 'connectTime' found in class 'org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration' and Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.NullPointerException,but if I run the same script directly like bzt asp.jmx its working fine.Please let me know

```
--- 
execution: 
  scenario: simple
modules:
  jmeter:
    path: "D:/apache-jmeter-2.12"  #jmeter path
scenarios: 
  simple: 
    script: "D:/apache-jmeter-2.12/bin/C4C_perf/asp.jmx"
```

Comment: Hi,above one is working fine and did some little changes in my yaml file.

Comment: so is the answer I provided ok ?

Comment: Hi Ubik,the yaml structure which I shown in above that only working fine instead of jmeter 2.12 I have used 3.1

Comment: So my answer is correct right ? So it should be accepted and upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is just that connect time didn’t exist in jmeter 2.12 which you are setting up:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html

Look at 2.13 release notes which introduced the feature.